# Flutter Android Unable to resolve class GradleException @ line 11, column 15

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, gradle, gradlew

For some reason I'm getting a gradle error in my project. In the app level build.gradle I'm getting this error `Unable to resolve class GradleException  @ line 11, column 15.` with the red squiggly underling 'GradleException' in this block:

```
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}
```

Comment: There's not likely much we can do here unless you give us instructions on how you got to this point, so that anyone can reproduce the issue on their own.  Just those three lines alone don't really tell us how your project is configured or what you might have changed from any defaults.

Answer (score 16):

Had the same problem. Go to the android/app/build.gradle. At the very top at this file you should see following code.

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}
```

Only remove "new" keyword from Properties and Exception lines.

```
def localProperties = Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}
```

#remove the new keyword

Answer (score 1):

Remove new keyword

```dart
def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw  GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}
```

Comment: vadimeche already provided this answer back in May. Please don't repeat answers.